# Shorter phrase or word to say `the day before yesterday`

Tags: word-meaning, phrases, spoken-english

Is there any phrase or word to say 'the day before yesterday' but shorter?

It seems very explicit say 'the day before yesterday' and in other languages there are sentences and words with this meaning.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: no, not really.  You're looking for a word like *anteayer* in Spanish?  We don't really have anything exactly like that.  We used to have "[ereyesterday](https://www.wordnik.com/words/ereyesterday)" (and "[overmorrow](http://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/Overmorrow)" for the day after tomorrow) but they are archaic now, and people will not understand those words if you use them.  "The day before yesterday" or "day before last" are the common ways to say it.

[There's a discussion of the topic at English.stackexchange.com here.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110074/a-more-succinct-expression-for-the-day-before-yesterday)